# How do I prevent python from freezing to work on a large number equation?

Tags: python, largenumber

Because it takes too much time to calculate for A, I'll want the calculation to stop and have the program continue on to calculate for B. It would also be helpful to know what error this is called.

```
A = 999999999999999999**999999999999999999

B = 9**9
```

The program still freezes when using threading.Timer()

```
import threading
import time

a = 1

def zzz():
    global a
    print('restarting')
    a = 0
    threading.Timer(1.0,zzz).start()
    a = 1


threading.Timer(1.0, zzz).start()



while 1:
    while a == 1:
        h = 999999999999999**999999999999999
```

Comment: You want some kind of timer that, if trigger, run into the next equation?

Comment: you can try threading.Timer()

Comment: My first question would be, do you really need to do that? Can you solve your issue in some other way? If not and you must do such calculation and use python to do that, I would suggest you to look up threads, specially worker thread. https://pymotw.com/2/threading/

Comment: When threading doesn't help, there is [`multiprocessing`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html).

Comment: @AhsanulHaque The program still freezes when using threading.Timer()

Comment: @vathek what kind of timer could I use?

Comment: The error is called running out of memory. `999999999999999**999999999999999` contains more than `10**18` digits. That's a billion times a billion. You do not have a billion billion bytes of RAM.

Comment: Do you really need large integers or just large numbers? It's not clear from the question. Why not use floats instead, e.g. 999999999999999.0?

Answer (score 0):

I believe the problem has been solved: adding ".0" at the end of one number will allow python to recognize that 99999999999999.0**99999999999999 is too large of a result and will output an error that can be ignored with try/except